# Gatsby page does not load when 'adwords' is in the page slug

Tags: frontend, gatsby, adblock

I have multiple Gatsby pages where the urls are `http://localhost:<port>/adwords` and `http://localhost:<port>/adwords/remarketing`, and both of these pages do not load with the AdBlock extension active in Google Chrome. I have tried changing the slug to /ad-words/, which fixes the problem, however I would like a solution in which I do not have to change the slugs for SEO reasons.

The error in the console says:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://localhost:<port>/page-data/adwords/page-data.json:1
```

So i'm guessing because this json file has the word 'adwords' in it, it's stopping the browser from downloading the file.

Any insights are greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I can only concur with your guess: Adblock sees 'adwords' and blocks the URL. I don't think there is a solution short of renaming or disabling Adblock, since - well - if there were, advertisers would use that workaround too (to push their ads through the Adblocker)

Comment: I agree, there is nothing really that Gatsby can do about that. You'd have to choose another name

Comment: Right ok, thanks for your input!